# In which scenario Distinct and Group by should be used in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by, distinct

It was asked in an interview.

There are many answers in **Stack overflow** like

1. Use `GROUP BY` if you use aggregate functions, like `AVG, MAX, MIN, SUM,` and `COUNT.` Other hand `DISTINCT` just removes duplicates.
2. There is no difference (in SQL Server, at least). Both queries use the same `execution plan`.

**My actual Question is**
 In case we are using aggregate functions we go for `Group By` function

If I’m not using `aggregate functions` in a query ,so in such case

1. If we are using `Group by` function there,why can't use `Distinct`?
   (As Both queries use the same `execution plan`.)
2. If we are using `Distinct` function there,why can't use `Group by`?
   (Both queries use the same `execution plan`.)

When and where `Group by` and `Distinct` should be Used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the distinct values, you can use either of the methods, which I think you already confirmed.

I would say if you're just fetching distinct values, use distinct to make it clear you're just doing that, and if you are grouping the results for aggregation or any other reason, then use group by.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also say to use `distinct` any time you're not aggregating.  Using `group by` requires making your queries slightly longer, and adjusting the `group by` clause whenever you adjust the `select`.  It also increases the chances of errors, as you can continue to `group by` something that you have removed from the `select`, which may cause your query not to actually return distinct values.

Additionally, it's clearer for someone reading your code, as JamesZ mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is clear: `distinct` is root of all evil :)

Why? Because usually `distinct` indicates, that you have some redundancy problems either in data, data structure or query design. Or even if your data is correct and queries are logical, then you effectively hide source of duplicate values - and months later, when you have to modify your query or answer your customer questions, you have hard time to understand, what happens under cover. And when you need to add some aggergates, then thing go messy very fast.

Using `group by` you are required to think clearly - which data is unique, what fields need to aggregate, why some data will appear twice and so on.

Well, there is place for `distinct` for me - short ad-hoc queries to find out, which values are used. Like `select distinct state from documents` or similar - but (as it happens often) if I need to know next, how many different kind of records I have, then I have to rewrite my ad-hoc using aggregates anyway: `select state, count(*) from documents group by state` :)